# registering file types on the iPhone browser

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

I know it's pretty simple to register custom file types in your app, but I can't figure out how to register those same file types in the internet browser. For example, say I want my program to be able to handle a .txt file. It works just fine from email, but when you're on the internet, all it does is display the text contained in the file, with no option to open it in an app that supports that extension. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS apps cannot take over file extensions in Safari, only protocols (i.e. `something://url`).